# How can i remove Azure Pipeline Build from GitHub checks

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I just setup CI/CD for a GitHub repo.

- The CI build which validates a pull request is setup up as GitHub Action.
- The CD build (which should run after the pull request was merged) is setup using Azure Pipelines as i would like to use the artifacts generated as a trigger for a Release Pipeline using Azure Pipelines as well.

The only thing that's still bugging me is, that the CD Build is also triggering automatically for a pull request and i can't figure out where i can configure those checks.

The checks currently running when a pull request is created are the following:
[image]

I want to get rid of the Continous Delivery Build here.

I tried to configure the branch protection rules but this has no effect:
[image]

On the Azure Pipeline side i completely disabled the triggers:
[image]
[image]

But this also has no visible effect to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested `Disable pull request validation` in the `Triggers` of the azure devops pipeline. On my side, it works well, and the build pipeline validation check is not displayed in the github pull request.

You can first check whether the pipeline source repo that you set the "`Disable pull request validation`" option corresponds to the github repo that created the pull request. Then try a few more times, it is possible that the settings are not applied immediately.

In addition, as workaround you can opt out of pull request validation entirely by specifying `pr: none` in yaml. Please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#opting-out-of-pr-validation).

```
# no PR triggers
pr: none
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, the changed setting just took some time to have an effect. now it's working. thank you!

Comment: Does this need a task? Like command line? Or it will just work even if not under step?